# Why the size of Pointer variable is 2 byte in C (16)?

Tags: c, pointers

Why ANSI has kept the size of pointer variable 2 byte in C (16 bit).

Comment: sorry, i have specified for 16 bit machine

Comment: It hasn't. It never defined the size of pointers in the first place. An *implementation* chooses a pointer size, and that makes perfect sense. What's the point of 64 bit pointers when you only have 65K of memory?

Comment: The size of a pointer variable depends on the compiler and the target system.

Comment: the size of pointers is implementation defined

Comment: They don't determine the size of pointers (or just about anything) on any implementation, the implementation creators do.

Comment: C++ and C are not the same language. I've removed the C++ tag as the question is about C.

Comment: @JBentley "C++ and C are not the same language", then why mark this C post as a duplicate of a C++ post?

Comment: @Chux I did not (IIRC my vote was for "unclear" since the question starts from a flawed premise and is therefore unanswerable). Unfortunately when people give multiple reasons for a close-vote, it displays the reason which got the most votes. I've flagged it.

Answer (score 2):

ANSI hasn't and never will, to find out what your implementation does use:

```
sizeof(void *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of a `void*` pointer is the address size of the CPU, as it has to be able to hold any possible memory address. For a 64-bit system, it has to be (at least) 64 bits.

Comment: "size of a void* pointer is the address size of the CPU" may be true in general, but not always so.  Example: pre 286 Intel processors had  segmented architectures, independently used 16 or 32 bit pointers for code, data and the address size was 20-bit.